$A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvalues, conclude $B^3=0$
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $5 \times 5$ complex matrices with the same eigenvalues. Suppose $m_A(x) = (x+1)^2$ and $p_B(x)=x^5$. Then $B^3 = 0$.
My question has already been answered as you can see. Below, I've reproduced the proof:
Proof.
By our knowledge of $m_A(x)$, the JNF blocks for $A$ appear as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix}$.  Then the possibilities for the JNF of $A$ are $2+1+1+1$ or $2+2+1$. In the first case, $A$ has four L.I. eigenvectors. In the second case, $A$ has three L.I. eigenvectors.
As $B$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$, this limits $B$ to having either $3$ or $4$ L.I. eignevectors as well. Thus, $B$ has at least three L.I. eigenvectors. So $B$ cannot have a JNF block larger than $3 \times 3$. Thus, $\deg(m_B(x)) \leq 3$. And so
$$m_B(x) \mid p_B(x) = x^5 \implies m_B(x) = x^3$$
Thus, $B^3 = 0$.
$$\hspace{10cm} \blacksquare$$
My question is not related at all to the proof; I agree with all that was stated above. My question is:
As $m_A(x) \mid p_B(x)$ always, it should follow that $\lambda = -1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but then $\lambda = -1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ which is impossible because $p_B(x) = x^5$. Am I misunderstood?

UPDATE: I was thinking that the problem was saying that they have the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues, which was the source of my confusion. The eigenvalues needn't be the same.

The link is about having common eigenvectors your problem statement is about common eigenvalues.  These are different things.

I assume $m_A$ means minimal polynomial of $A$ and $p_B$ means characteristic polynomial of $B$. If so, how can $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvalues? Clearly, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ but it isn't an eigenvalue of $A$.

@Grigor Did you mean to say that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors?

@BenGrossmann Oh, maybe THAT is my issue. I kept interchanging the terms in my head but I see now that this clarification fixes my confusion.
